# Separar valores repetidos em uma lista

Tags: c#

Tenho uma lista assim:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,1,5,3,4,3,4]
```

Como gerar uma nova lista apenas com um valor de cada:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

A primeira lista é um `List<int>` a segunda pode vir em qualquer tipo de lista.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Por definição matemática, um conjunto é uma estrutura em que cada elemento aparece uma única vez. No C#, um conjunto é representado por [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx).

Gerando um `HashSet<int>` da sua lista, você terá os elementos sem repetição:

```
var conjunto = new HashSet<int>(lista);
```

[Veja uma demonstração aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S2ZRGg).

Comment: Eu não conhecia esse comando, porém, ao ler mais sobre ele no SOEn, não vi vantagens sobre o `LINQ`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247442/when-should-i-use-the-hashsett-type e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance

Comment: @ismael É só uma forma alternativa de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 12):

Utilize o [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) para remover os items duplicados, gerando um novo objeto.

```
List<int> novaListaDeInteiros = listaDeInteirosVelha.Distinct().ToList();
```

Isto irá retornar uma sequência `List<int>` preenchida sem repetir os dados.

Comment: Não precisa do `Select`, é repetição desnecessária.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, resposta editada.

Comment: Agora tem meu voto =)

Answer (score 7):

Utilize o [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb920306(v=vs.90).aspx) para retornar os distintos elementos da sua lista.

```
using System.Linq;

List<int> lista = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4 } ;
lista.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 7):

A função `Distinct` do `Linq` elimina dados duplicados de uma lista no .Net Framework:

```
var lista = new List<int> {1,1,1,2,2,1,5,3,4,3,4};
var listaSemDuplicidade = lista.Distinct();
```

Um exemplo funcional pode ser [visto aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0YPfAi).